# How do I keep window in focus when moving it to another monitor?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm using xmonad with 2 monitors and `XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens`. It works mostly fine, but one problem I have is that when I move a window to another monitor, it looses focus

The code that is responsible for the placement is here:

```
     [((m .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f))
           | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_e, xK_w, xK_r] [0..] -- switched e and w to accomodate my monitor setup
           , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, controlMask)]]
```

However, I am very new to Haskell and cannot make any sense of it

How do I modify the code above to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so clear to me what you really want. I am assuming you'd like to move the current focused windows to other workspace/monitor and keep the focus on that windows. Isn't it?

Looking at the snipet, I am not sure which keybindings you'd like. Let me explain

```hs
-- This comprehension list expands as below
[ ( (m .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (windows . f) )
| (key, sc) <- zip [xK_e, xK_w, xK_r] [0..] 
, (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, controlMask)]
]
  
-- mod + 0 + e moves focus to workspace 0 (but not the focused window)
-- mod + ctrl + e moves focused window to workspace 0 (but doesn't move the focus)
-- mod + 0 + w moves focus to workspace 1 (but not the focused window)
-- etc...
[ ( (0           .|. modm, xK_e), screenWorkspace 0 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.view) )
, ( (controlMask .|. modm, xK_e), screenWorkspace 0 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.shift) )
, ( (0           .|. modm, xK_w), screenWorkspace 1 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.view) )
, ( (controlMask .|. modm, xK_w), screenWorkspace 1 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.shift) )
, ( (0           .|. modm, xK_r), screenWorkspace 2 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.view) )
, ( (controlMask .|. modm, xK_r), screenWorkspace 2 >>= flip whenJust (windows . W.shift) )
]
```

As you can see, you have different keybindigs for moving the focus, and moving the focused window. I guess that you want a single keybind to do both at the same time. And I assume that you want `Mod+CTRL+w/e/r` to move to other workspace. In that case you need to modify that list by the following

```hs
[ ( (controlMask .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust (\wid -> windows $ W.view wid . W.shift wid) )
   | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_e, xK_w, xK_r] [0..] 
]
```

Since the code above is a little bit cryptic I'd recommend to define an auxiliar function at the top level

```hs
moveCurrentWindowsAndFocusIt :: WorkspaceId -> X ()
moveCurrentWindowsAndFocusIt wid = windows $ W.view wid . W.shift wid

-- This is the where your keybindings are
mykeybindings =
  ...
 [ ( (controlMask .|. modm, key), screenWorkspace sc >>= flip whenJust moveCurrentWindowsAndFocusIt  )
   | (key, sc) <- zip [xK_e, xK_w, xK_r] [0..] 
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!